# Use of waitUntilCompleted

Tags: ios, metal

When I run a CommandBuffer with several passes, I normally attach to the end a `waitUntilCompleted` command. This time though, even if there are several encoders/command buffers, I present the data directly to the screen, so I don't need to pass anything to the CPU. I guess I can just do without the wait, is that right?

What about a test though? What would be the best way to wait for the GPU to finish from outside a class?

Comment: Interesting. I think you can do without the wait until complete, but then it would no longer be possible to know when it finished. Using an output vector to trigger a delegate would fail. Since it wouldn't wait for the gpu and return a nil (or pre shader run value). Maybe it is possible to check what is on screen? I personally use completion handlers that return after the `waitUntilCompleted` they either trigger the next pass or trigger a delegate.

Comment: @RMenke I too used completion handlers in the end, I set a flag and with that I know that the processing for the object is finished. All is left to do in the test is waiting on the runloop until the flag is true.